# PHP/MySQL editing database and calling values

Tags: php, mysql

I've done some work with PHP/MySQL in the past but not huge amounts. This should be a fairly simple problem I would have thought.

I have a table called 'user' inside which there are columns called 'id' (primary key), 'name', 'room', 'subject, and 'fb' (facebook profile URL). I need to add values to each of these eg.

```
id: 1
name: bob
room: B4
subject: maths
fb: www.facebook.com/bob
```

I then need to search all values in PHP based on a particular room eg.

```
if (room called B4 exists) {
$name = name;
$room = room;
$subject = subject;
$fb = fb;
echo $name;
}
```

Sorry if I'm asking for too much guidance, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could clear it up for me somewhat.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code set up yet, like a database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add values, use `mysql_query` with `INSERT INTO ...` like this:

```
 //connect to mysql and select database
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('put_your_database_name_here') or die("Can not select database");

 //insert data into MySQL
 mysql_query("insert into user (id, name, room, subject, fb) values ('1', 'bob', 'B4', 'maths', 'www.facebook.com/bob')");
```

---

Then to search values do like this:

```
 //connect to mysql and select database
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('put_your_database_name_here') or die("Can not select database");


 //fetch data from MySQL
 $result = mysql_query("select * from user where room = 'B4'");

 //iterate over each row and do what you want.
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
      $name = $row['name'];
      $room = $row['room'];
      $subject = $row['subject'];
      $fb = $row['fb'];
      echo $name;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. the SQL query works fine but the php isn't working for some reason..

Comment: Does it give you any error? Did you remember to put correct username, password, tablename, etc in the code ?